# Google Cloud Airflow Composer

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am trying to trigger a python script that i upload in GCS bucket, using Airflow composer. The task was sucess but actually it did non run and new data did not created. I tried to use BashOperator or PythonOperator but it does not work. I test the python script by running it via Cloud shell and it works properly[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkPbx.png)

BashOperator, PythonOperator
Trying to trigger the code, new data should be added in Bigerquery